# How to align the divs/profile cards horizontally in Meteor JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor

Can any one please let me know how can we display the profile cards horizontally in meteor js.

```
Please find my code below:


import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
    export default class MyProfileCard extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
         <div className="card profile-photo" >
          <div className="brand-myImage">
              <img src= {this.props.imgSrc ? this.props.imgSrc : "img.jpg"} />
           </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
    DiscoverCard.propTypes = {
      imgSrc: PropTypes.string,
    };
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at [flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

In your case give the following css a try:

```
.cardContainer {
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: row
}
```

where `cardContainer` is the class of the div that wraps your component

Comment: Many thanks Michel,

Along with

.cardContainer {
  display: flex,
  flex-direction: row
}

Adding 

.profile-photo{
  float:left;
  height:30%;
  width:30%;
}

worked for me.

Thank yu.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Bootstrap` then you can simply use rows and columns to align cards horizontally .

Answer (score 0):

Adding the below to my CSS worked for me.

```
.container {
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:row;
}

.profile-photo{
  float:left;
  height:30%;
  width:30%;
}
```

Thanks
...Vamsi.